# How to Update Document properties using CMIS

Tags: java, alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-webscripts, cmis-workbench

I have one external web application through that i connected to alfresco repository using CMIS.

I am already  able to upload document in to repository or able to download n view document.

Now my requirement is, I have to Update Specific Documents Properties.

So can any one please provide sample code or steps to update document properties Using CMIS.

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: Please show your sample code.

Comment: @coderz.................    which sample code you are looking for??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this worked fine for me

```
Session session = getSession(serverUrl, username, password);
Document targetFile = (Document) session.getObject(path);
Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
properties.put(PropertyIds.NAME, name);
targetFile.updateProperties(properties);
```

In my example you only have to replace `name` with whatever you want

Hope that helped you

Comment: Yes, I will required Delete file option also. please share the sample code if you have.

Comment: yes i have please ask a question and i will give an answer @deeps

Comment: did you ask your question @deeps ?!?

Comment: I have asked the question. Please reply.