# RESTful Service to change properties of Alfresco file from Bonita BPM Community

Tags: rest, alfresco, bonita

Guys!
I'm new to Bonita BPM and especially to Alfresco Community and I need your help. What I'm trying to do is to create a process in Bonita BPM 7.4.1 that can upload a file in Alfresco repository and change the properties to that file with values I set in Bonita. I have created a process in Bonita, that is using a CMIS connector to upload the file and it is working perfectly. I also created my custom model and custom aspects in Alfresco and they are containing my specific metadata for my file. What my problem is how to send the values of these custom properties to Alfresco. I guess I have to use a Restful service, that can set them up, but I can not find any examples and I'm a little bit confused.
Is there anyone that have had these issues before? I will greatly appreciate your help and any examples.

Comment: You can (assuming you're using CMIS 1.1) easily set custom properties using CMIS. Why not do it that way?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: How I can set the custom properties using CMIS ?

Comment: you can refer this tutorial [link](http://ecmarchitect.com/alfresco-developer-series-tutorials/content/tutorial/tutorial.html#cmis-1.0-and-the-alfresco-opencmis-extension-library)

Comment: you can see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39363131/how-to-update-document-properties-using-cmis/39363368#39363368

Comment: Example: 
POST /alfresco/service/api/metadata/node/workspace/SpacesStore/85fe8072-dabe-4453-8214-a55bdcfc1814

Content-Type: application/json
{ properties: {"cm:title":"title5555", "cm:name":"title5555"} }

Answer (score 0):

Note that in order to update your file metadata in Alfresco you can use the Bonita REST connector that is provided now by default with Bonita Studio.

Simply configure to perform the POST call as suggested by Nilson Morais in the comments.